# What is "compare to category" in Google Trends analysis?

Tags: google-trends

I'm trying to analyze which is the best app between **WAMP vs XAMPP** based on the Google Trends results for those terms.

In this first chart, I have left "compare to category" unchecked.  *WAMP is above the XAMPP*
[image]

In the second chart, I have left "compare to category" checked  *XAMPP is above the WAMP*
[image]

[google-trends WAMP vs XAMPP](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cat=0-5-32&q=WAMP,+XAMPP&cmpt=q)

What is the difference between leaving this setting checked or unchecked?  What "category" am I comparing the results to?